# basics of causality: miguel hernan book doubt

Tags: causality

While reading "Causal Inference" book from Miguel A. Hernán, he starts the book with the example:

> Zeus is a patient waiting for a heart transplant. On January 1, he
>   receives a new heart. Five days later, he dies. Imagine that we can
>   somehow know, perhaps by divine revelation, that had Zeus not received
>   a heart transplant on January 1, he would have been alive five days
>   later. Equipped with this information most would agree that the
>   transplant caused Zeus’s death. The heart transplant intervention had
>   a causal effect on Zeus’s five-day survival. Another patient, Hera,
>   also received a heart transplant on January 1. Five days later she was
>   alive. Imagine we can somehow know that, had Hera not received the
>   heart on January 1, she would still have been alive five days later.
>   Hence the transplant did not have a causal effect on Hera’s five-day
>   survival.

But immediately he contradicts the example by saying:

> These two vignettes illustrate how humans reason about
>   causal effects: We compare (usually only mentally) the outcome when an
>   action A is taken with the outcome when the action A is withheld.

Why is he saying that we compare taking vs withholding, when he clearly says in the Zeus/Hera example that we do not withheld anything, we take action A (heart surgery) on both? It seems to me a big contradiction in the first paragraphs of the book of two really important authors...

Comment: The "withholding" has to do with a counterfactual: not performing the heart surgery. A counterfactual is a "what if..." scenario: we essentially do a thought experiment, and reason about what would have happened if the surgery had not occurred.